# Java Android : How to extract method with context as parameter

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I'm trying to extract a method that returns song information to a new class so I can call its instance from more than one class.

**The method :**

```
public int getSongList(ContentResolver resolver){
        //retrieve song info
        ContentResolver musicResolver = resolver;
        Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

        if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
            //get columns
            int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            //add songs to list
            do {
                long thisId         = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                String thisTitle    = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                String thisArtist   = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
                songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
            }
            while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Assuming that the above method is placed in MainActivity. Here's how I'm trying to instantiate it from a fragment.

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);

            View rootView   = inflater.inflate(R.layout.library_songs, container, false);

            this.mView      = rootView;

            songView = (ListView) mView.findViewById(R.id.song_list);
            songList = new ArrayList<Song>();
            new MainActivity().getSongList(mView.getContext().getContentResolver())

            Collections.sort(songList, new Comparator<Song>(){
              public int compare(Song a, Song b){
                return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
            }
            });

            SongAdapter songAdt = new SongAdapter(mView.getContext(), songList);
            songView.setAdapter(songAdt);

            return rootView;
        }
```

**Error :**

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.auxiline.audioscope.MainActivity.getSongList(MainActivity.java:219)

Answer (score 0):

calling

```
new MainActivity().getSongList(mView.getContext().getContentResolver())
```

because you are creating a new object of MainActivity and in that object the songList object is null.
Also it seems that you have tow copies of songList one in the MainActivity and the other in the fragment so you have to decide witch one to use.
to solve this you can pass an object of the MainActivity to the fragment in the fragment constructor:

```
public MyFragment(MainActivity activity,...){ .... }
```

so when you create the fragment object in the MainActivity you use :

```
MyFragment mMyFragment = new MyFragment(MainActivity.this , ... );
```

Also you have to rewrite the getSongList method to make it use the songList object from the fragment :

```
public int getSongList(ContentResolver resolver,ArrayList<Song> songList)
```